# Windows 7 Benchmarking Tools That Drive Microsoft Office Applications

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, benchmark

Are there any benchmarking tools that can actually drive MS Office applications in Windows 7 rather than just running various synthetic loads?

I'm looking to measure the impact on user experience (i.e. response time) of various system configurations (e.g. with and without anti-virus, disk encryption, etc.) and would like this to be done using real MS Office applications. Specifically I'm looking for the ability to measure, for example, the start time for Microsoft Word, time to load a large file, time to save a large file, and so on, in an automated, repeatable manner.

Comment: The BAPco suggestion below looks like an excellent solution, however, I'm being told that much cheaper (or free) alternatives exist. I've not been able to find any, hence my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [BapCo](http://www.bapco.com/) is a standard industry benchmark.

Comment: Wow, great recommendation! I just wanted to contribute a link showing that their latest version of SYSmark only supports Office 2010. http://www.bapco.com/products/sysmark2012/applications.php

Answer (score -2):

You could use benchmark files like [this one for excel](http://exceltrader.net/excel-benchmark/).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers